# PHP Pass file_get_contents() data to function

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Is it possible to pass `file_get_contents()` data to another functions? See below for a better understanding.

```
function getURL($search){
    $url      = "http://www.example.com?search=".$search;
    $data     = file_get_contents($url);
    $formated = formatData($data);
    return $formated;
}
function formatData($data){
   $format = $data;
   //some formating here
   return $format;
}
```

This is the kind of thing I am trying to do as currently, if I want to do this, I have to call the `file_get_contents()` function again, but this slows down the application as it's making a call to the same site twice.

Any help would be nice

Comment: Did you try it? Your example above should work.

Comment: Your example works just fine. What is not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_get_contents() returns a string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). You can pass the string to another function (just like in your example). Is that not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cURL instead of file_get_contents() and it will be a bit faster.

[cURL manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)